# Why preschooler is acting this way?

Tags: pre-schooler, behavior

My son just turn 3 this week but he is known for his naughty behaviour but lately it has turned into embarrassment. E.g. throwing creams on carpet and rubbing it, throwing milk on wall etc. He do cries a lot, when I ask him why he do that, he like to make a puppy face and smooches against me. I am scared of his behaviour as he can do same with someone else and I very cautious of people who are evil may take advantage of him. He cries too much about anything which he doesn’t get. Although he is very intelligent and helpful too

What should we do to stop him? He might do some big damage.

Answer (score 2):

It is really strange to address why-questions to 3 years boy. He just now had learned to pronounce words and repeat some sentences, and you ask him "why?"

i guess he don't know why). Maybe it is very pleased and fun to throw milk at the wall, you should try, i think you didn't ever same, maybe that is better then sweets and sex to look how is milk flow along the wall?

He tried to get the first experience of action in the world, he is interested in something, let him get the experience. But all his trying ends with your swearing. So, you sworn at his interest and cognitive instinct... but he is smart boy, he know that you can't resist his poppy face, so he played with you in this game by your rules. And he won you with poppy face. He likes to won maybe.

And he is dare, he don't fear you and your sworn. It is his character, his dare and his "naughty". Let him be a creator of the game rules: Let him throw the milk. You may to buy some milk and throw it together, ofc not inside the house, not in the kitchen, in bathroom or outdoors, change the wall, bathroom maybe. You buy to toys to him, but he want to play with milk(why milk is not a toy?) and you "toys", or maybe he wants to play with you. He don't know why, he didn't do this yet, he just trying to do something, before he able to say why. Let him do his mad things but with a bit of control. Teach him how to control his interest. And when he finished the research i think he ll able to answer you why he do this. Let him finish that he will wish.

Comment: Exactly. You need to redirect the behaviour to something he can do, explain why we don't throw milk (its expensive, it makes a mess) attempt to engage him in cleaning up "Oh no, we need to clean up this big mess, can you get the cloth from the kitchen?" and model tidying up. Then get the kid outside and doing appropriate messy play. Finger painting, throwing water outside etc. Its also on you to ensure that tempting, messy things are left out of sight!

Comment: I think I must have mentioned that he is danger to himself by sticking stuff in sockets if unsupervised he once bought huge tv onto him self.

Comment: @localhost what the problem to create safe space for him? he doesn't need a tv, he needs your time, and your care, and safe space for experiments, if you not wish that tv should be his parent, ofc. if the tv is not an idol, if it represents a danger you may throw it out, it is just a ordinary thing. Sockets may have a protection from babies, and house voltage usually can't to kill, only hurts, less hurt then you fear and nervous. I heard many fears about voltage accidents, but i never heard that is someone dead(except in bath) or got more serious then small shok  an experience of a danger.